# BigQuery + javascript (tabledata.insertAll)

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is my code:

```
function runQuery(){
    var json = JSON.stringify({"string": "eight", "number": "8", "id": "8"});
    var body = {
        "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
        "rows": [
            {
                "insertId": "8",
                "json": json
            }
        ]
    };

    var request = gapi.client.bigquery.tabledata.insertAll({
        'projectId': project_id,
        'datasetId': 'newTest',
        'tableId': 'newTable',
        'content': body
    });

    request.execute(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

But this code return error: **No records present in table data append request. (400)**
Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved:

```
        var request = gapi.client.bigquery.tabledata.insertAll({
            'projectId': projectId,
            'datasetId': datasetId,
            'tableId': tableId,
            "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
            "rows":[
                {
                    "insertId": "10",
                    "json": {"id": "10", "string": "ten", "number": "10"}
                }
            ]
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Spent a lot of time on the same issue. 
dbepcepk's answer resulted in the error:

"Error: Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "rows": Cannot bind query parameter. 'rows' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types."

Here is how I got around it:

Note the JSON Key "resource" defining the TableDataInsertAllRequest object

```
const request ={
        "projectId": projectId,
        "datasetId": datasetId, 
        "tableId": tableId,
        "resource":{
            "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllRequest",
            "skipInvalidRows": false,
            "ignoreUnknownValues": false,
            "templateSuffix":"",
            "rows": [{"json": {"test":true}]
        }
    }

  client.tabledata.insertAll(
    request,
    (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(data);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Following the github link resulting in a 404 error.

Answer (score 0):

You can't append data to the sample data set. Create your own to perform your inserts.

Comment: good answer, better if you can be more specific. use links and examples where possible. =)

Comment: Thanks @JackDev, I will do that next time!